# same file upload to multiple references in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I've to insert a file to two references in firebase storage and add the name and download Url of the files to other two references in the firebase database. The files a getting uploaded to the firebase storage as expected but the name and download Url are not getting stored in the database as expected. Instead of one pair of name and download Url being added to each one reference in database, both pairs are getting added to the same reference.

```
case R.id.facultySpaceStudentRadioButton :
             if(validInputs(fileChoosed)){
                 sendFile("ASSIGNMENT");
             }
             break;

        case R.id.facultySpaceParentRadioButton :
            if(validInputs(fileChoosed)){
                sendFile("PERFORMANCE");
            }
            break;

        case R.id.facultySpaceBothRadioButton :
            if(validInputs(fileChoosed)){
                sendFile("ASSIGNMENT");
                sendFile("PERFORMANCE");
            }
            break;

        default :
            if(fileChoosed == null){
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                fileNotChoosed();
            } else {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setCancelable(false).setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }).setTitle("Alert !").setMessage("Please choose a receiver !");
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
    }

}

private void sendFile(String recipient){
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(recipient)
            .child(facultySpaceStream).child(facultySpaceBatchEditText.getText().toString());
    mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mStorageReference.child(recipient + "/").child(facultySpaceStream + "/")
            .child(facultySpaceBatchEditText.getText().toString() + "/" + fileChoosed.getLastPathSegment())
            .putFile(fileChoosed)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Upload upload = new Upload(facultySpaceFileNameEditText.getText().toString(), taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                    mDatabaseReference.child(mDatabaseReference.push().getKey()).setValue(upload);
                    resetFields();
                    Toast.makeText(FacultySpace.this, "File sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    facultySpaceFileNameEditText.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(FacultySpace.this, "Sending Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress = ((100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                    mProgressDialog.setMessage(new DecimalFormat("##.#").format(progress) + "% Sending File...");
                }
            });
}
```

As you can see, i'm using the switch case, first and second case are working perfectly as expected but when the third case is executed, the database receives improper values.

Comment: file already store in firebase database. I think you can change the name for the third time.

Comment: Yes, files are getting stored in the firebase storage at proper locations but their names and Download Url are not getting stored in the proper locations. For eg, in third case, when the sendFile("ASSIGNMENT") and sendFile("PERFORMANCE") are executed, the details of the files are supposed to stored in the ASSIGNMENT node and PERFORMANCE node respectively, instead two datas are getting stored in the PERFORMANCE node out of which one has blank name (" ").

Comment: refer this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-tutorial-android/